# What area of math studies the shortest distance between two points located in the surface of an arbitrary 3D or higher dimensional shape?

Tags: geometry, puzzle

Recently I was trying to solve this puzzle:

[image: puzzle]

Which I got from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbpgvQvM008). It doesn't say it in the picture but both the ant and the honey are 6 inches away from the side edges. The solution I thought of was basically the same one they give in the video: Look at the cuboid like it is a a plane by "opening" it and then calculating the minimum distance by calculating the lenght of the line that goes by the ant and the honey. Different ways of opening it give different distances so after trying out many configurations one can find the minimum one. The main problem with this approach is that it doesn't actually prove that the minimum distance is 40, it's just the shortest one we could find using this method.

Not only that but how can we generalize it? Are we gonna have to try tons of configurations again if the points A and B change positions? What about other shapes such as a sphere or whatever this is:

[image: shape]

What if I was given two points and had to find the minimum distance in that shape? What about the minimum distance between two points in a higher dimensional shape?

Anyways, I suddenly became interested in these sorts of questions and I want to know, what area or areas of mathematics, if any, attempt to answer these questions? I would like to study it in the future.

I'm kind of new in math, so for me these sorts of questions look almost impossible, but maybe they are trivial for someone who specializes in whatever area of mathematics studies them.

Comment: Riemannian geometry and geodesic should do your job